# Is include path lookup somehow supported in the standard library?

Tags: c++, include, std, include-path

I know the C++ standard library caters to C++ programs, not C++ compilers. But - is there some facility in the standard library for looking up include files - on the filesystem or wherever they would get looked up in on the target system - given the kind of string you would use in an include directive (i.e. `<foo/bar.h>` or `"foo/bar.h"`)?

Comment: The standard supports implementations on file systems without paths, so cannot easily specify how an "include path" shouild work. It doesn't even require `<name>` to be a file at all, just a header (whatever that is).

Comment: @BoP: Well, filesystem exists and "supports" systems without paths, so I don't think that should be a hindrance. But - I'm not optimistic. Anyway, tweaked the question to address this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in tool which implements that and the main problem with that is that the standard doesn't seem to have this logic standardised. [[cpp.include]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#:%23include) part describes it as follows (emphasis mine):

> - A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```cpp
> # include < h-char-sequence > new-line
> ```
>
> **searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `<` and `>`** delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.
>
> - A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```cpp
> # include " q-char-sequence " new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. **The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read**
>
> ```cpp
> # include < h-char-sequence > new-line
> ```
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including `>` characters, if any) from the original directive.

Thus, the only thing we reliably know from the standard is that there is a fallback rule from an implementation-defined lookup of `"q-char-sequence"` to another implementation-defined lookup of `<h-char-sequence>` (while filesystem is compiler-agnostic and rather platform-dependent, this lookup rule is the other way around - compiler-dependent but almost-platform-agnostic)

---

I was, however, once assigned an entry-test task to implement a tool which finds the missing and cyclic includes. For that task I took the conventional rules where `".."` tokens are searched for in the current directory and `<..>` are searched for in the "system-folders". In this scenario, the logic of such a function looks quite straightforward:

```cpp
tdw::Analyser::path_type tdw::Analyser::findIncludeParentPath(const Include& _sourceFile, const path_type _currentPath, const std::vector<path_type>& _includePaths) {
    using namespace std::filesystem;

    // Follows C standard "6.10.2 Source file inclusion" - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=182
    if(_sourceFile.type == Include::Type::q_char) {
        const auto searchPath = _currentPath / _sourceFile.path;

        if(is_regular_file(searchPath)) {
            return _currentPath;
        }
    }

    for(const auto& includePath : _includePaths) {
        const auto searchPath = includePath / _sourceFile.path;
        if(is_regular_file(searchPath)) {
            return includePath;
        }
    }

    return path_type();
}
```

The parameters and types have the following meaning:

- `tdw::Analyser::path_type` is just an alias of form `using path_type = typename std::filesystem::path`;
- `Include` describes a separate include entry as follows:

```cpp
struct Include {
    enum class Type {
        q_char, h_char, pp_tokens
    };

    const path_type path;
    const Type type;
};
```

Here `path` doesn't refer to absolute path, but rather `h-char-sequence` or `q-char-sequence` parsed from corresponding directives.

- `_sourceFile` - a file where `include` directive is found in
- `_currentPath` - the (absolute) path, `_sourceFile` is located in
- `_includePaths` - the paths where `h-char-sequence` tokens are supposed to be looked for in

**P.S.** You can find complete project [here](https://github.com/TheDreamsWind/TEST-Tensor-DInclude/).